# How to convert Varchar to Date?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-date-functions

I have a table - Order and I have a field "Order_Date" which is in Varchar format - '20150804'.

```
select order_date from order
output- 20150804
```

I want to convert order_date- **'20150804'**  into Date format- **'07-SEP-15'**

Comment: the date is not correct after converting...

Comment: On a side note: `'20150804' into Date format- '07-SEP-15'` I am considering it as a typo as no query will do that conversion for you. Considering it as YYYYMMDD format, it will be 04-AUG-15

Comment: Re-tagged with `oracle` based on the initial `plsql` tag.

Comment: **Never**, ever store dates as varchar. Fix your table and create a real `date` column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
select to_char(to_date('20150804', 'yyyymmdd'), 'dd-MON-yy') from dual;
```

In your actual query it would be like:

```
select to_char(to_date(order_date, 'yyyymmdd'), 'dd-MON-yy') from order
```

Comment: You're converting the date string to a different string representation here, which might be useful, but I think that only the conversion to a DATE data type is called for here.

Comment: @DavidAldridge:- Yes I agree but I was waiting for OP to respond. And I would instead recommend not to store date as string to OP so as to avoid these kinds of problem